# If TeX GUI used, identify which one? LuaLaTeX in use

Tags: luatex, editors

My custom LuaLaTeX document class does not play nicely with some TeX GUI programs. That is because I have re-written some basic LaTeX commands. If a user tries to choose commands from a GUI menu, then the results will be unexpected.

Therefore, I instruct users to plain-code in a text editor, or use TeXWorks only. The reasons are documented. But of course, who actually reads instructions?

My question: Since my document necessarily uses LuaLaTeX, is it possible for a TeX document to identify whether it is loaded in a GUI? If so, is it possible to detect which one? "Other than TeXWorks" would suffice.

I expect that the answer to my question is "NO," but if there is some short and obvious code, I'd like to know. Not asking for deep thought. (LuaLa)TeX methods only.

Comment: Can you give some examples of things that don't work and why?

Comment: Yes. `{\large text}` does not work! The text will be the same size. This is by intent. Reason why: The user is not permitted to change the font size in that manner, for deep reasons having to do with layout. Therefore, my code has `\let\large\relax` to make it go away. The file will not crash or produce an error. But the result is unexpected if the user did not read the instructions. Some GUIs have a way of inserting size code from a menu; won't work.

Comment: So long as the documents don't break, I would be inclined to let people do whatever they want.  I don't really see the difference between someone using an editor and choosing a 'large' menu item vs. entering `{\large ... }` in the source themselves; since the latter won't work either.  This seems to be a bit of a non problem, really.

Comment: Why should someone who types `\large` be less confused by this behaviour then someone who clicks a button? Don't deprive your users of the possibility to use whatever editor they know/like/have/...

Comment: Also instead of trying to manage users' behaviour via the editor, why not set your redefined commands to produce console class warnings or messages. Then people will see clearly that certain commands have been redefined and aren't available.  Changing things silently isn't in your best interest.

Comment: @AlanMunn That's a good idea, about settting the redefined commands to produce class warnings. Definitely solves the problem, and does not interfere with use of GUI. Please post as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't actually come right out and order users to change their behavior. They wouldn't listen if I did!

Comment: But why would you even want to specify the editor used?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually, I'm not specifying the editor. I made the assumption that someone hand-typing the code has read instructions, but that someone choosing from a menu in a GUI did not read instructions. TeXWorks doesn't have that capability. In other words, I am trying to predict user behavior. Probably over-reaching.

Comment: "I made the assumption that someone hand-typing the code has read instructions". Clearly you haven't met @DavidCarlisle. :)

Comment: Why are you redefining basic LaTeX commands? If the changes make that much of a difference, give them custom names, don't make things confusing for your users (because even if they read the documentation it can still be confusing to have known commands do unexpected behavior). Tweaking the commands such that they still do mostly the same thing/add additional behavior without changing the original seems reasonable to me, though, like what hyperref and cite do with `\cite` and `\ref`.

Comment: @JAB I am re-defining those comands because they cannot be used for the purpose intended. Also, "because I can." Yes, I do have substitute commands. But unless I re-define the originals, a new user might not realize that something was unexpected, due to the length of the documents. Incidentally, I turned off all the hyperref modifications, for a related reason. My document class does not add functionality to LaTeX. Instead, it subtracts functionality that is inapplicable to the end usage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is that there is no way for TeX to know how the file its processing was edited, nor should there be.

And there's no functional difference between someone typing one of your redefined commands directly into their source document and clicking on some IDE's menu item: the effect on the output will be mysterious either way, assuming they haven't read your documentation.

So instead of trying to manage users' behaviour via the editor, you should set your redefined commands to produce console class warnings or messages. Then people will see clearly that certain commands have been redefined and aren't available. Changing things silently by using `\let\command\relax` isn't in your best interest.